# Application.Current.Exit event not triggering in plugin model

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF plugin which runs in a WPF desktop application (no silverlight). My plugin needs to do some cleanup when the application exits, and hence I added the following event handler to my plugin class, but the event is not reaching my handler!!!

```
    void Setup()
    {

            Application.Current.Exit += new ExitEventHandler(Current_Exit); 
    }

    void Current_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
            {
                logger.LogEvent("Application Exit event fired");
                DoCleanup();
            }
```

i debugged through the app and was able to check that the Setup() method was called successfully, but the event handler was not called. Any ideas, why this would happen

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF app does not execute Application\_Exit method when user closes main window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617137/wpf-app-does-not-execute-application-exit-method-when-user-closes-main-window)

Comment: Are you running your plug-ins in a different AppDomain?

Comment: Does your main application part get the Exit event? Maybe you want to adjust your plugin so that it has some sort of method that will be called by the main application part on application exit. You can even have an `IPlugin` interface with such a callback method to make it more official.

Comment: the plugin is not running in a seperate app domain. the exit method othe plugin container event has a bug and hence I was trying to get it from framework

Comment: the related question also has no correct answer